# What is the QueryDSL equivalent of the JPQL `index()` function?

Tags: java, querydsl

For example how can I convert the following JPQL query to QueryDSL?

```
SELECT p
FROM F f
JOIN f.p p
WHERE index(p)=0
```

where `F.p` is of type `List<P>`.

Comment: I've seen a proposal at https://bugs.launchpad.net/querydsl/+bug/765710 but probably it is not implemented yet...

Comment: Actually it had been fixed in 2.2.0-beta4 according to http://bugs.launchpad.net/querydsl/+bug/765710 ticket

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the *get()* method in [ListPath](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.6/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/ListPath.html#get-int-) which implements the *index()* function.

Just as an example, here is a JPA query (QueryDSL 4.0.6) which gets a catalog entity whose second child category (index 1) has given name:

```
public Catalog findSecondCatalogChildCategoryByName(String Name) {
    return new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
            .selectFrom(catalog)
            .where(
                    catalog.rootCategories.get(1).name.eq(name)
            ).fetchOne();
}
```

Note: In this example, rootCategories field has java.util.List type